# How to append to char arrays in Objective c

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, char, append

I have two `char` arrays -

```
char* c1[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, ... 0x016 };
char* c2[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, ... 0x016 };
```

I want a `char` (`char* result`) with appended bytes of `c1` and `c2`

Comment: are you sure those `*`s are meant to be there?

Comment: Though you might be using this code in an objective c environment, what you have got there is just pure c so I have amended your tags accordingly. Also, the [iPhone] tag is for questions regarding the iPhone and iPod hardware, not software developed on those platforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate  memory, and copy the data from the old array to the new one.

```
char* result;
result=(char*)malloc( sizeof(c1) + sizeof(c) );
memcpy(result, c, sizeof(c));
memcpy(result+sizeof(c), c1, sizeof(c1));
```

When you are finish your work with result free memory with `free(result);`